# How to override output of checkout page in Commerce

Tags: commerce

I want to override the output of the order completion page. I need to include custom markup, as well as data from the order. As a matter of personal preference (and for organizational purposes), I'd rather do this in code, in my module, rather than in Rules. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Are you familiar with coding in drupal using hooks and custom modules?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like using `hook_commerce_checkout_pane_info_alter(&$checkout_panes)` or `hook_commerce_checkout_page_info_alter(&$checkout_pages)` would be the best options. There are also hooks that allow you to create your own checkout panes/pages from scratch if necessary (`hook_commerce_checkout_pane_info()` and `hook_commerce_checkout_page_info()`). I would suggest reading more about them [here](http://www.drupalcommerce.org/developer-guide/core-architecture/info-hooks/checkout-info-hooks) and checking out the specific examples (about page/pane info hook implementations) that you can find in the Drupal Commerce submodule (mostly Checkout) files.

Comment: Yeah, the code in commerce_checkout.checkout_pane.inc gives a good implementation example. I should be able to override the output with hook_commerce_checkout_pane_info_alter(). Thanks for the tip.